# Chai Test returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, backend, chai

I'm trying to write a very simple Chai test that just checks the status of the server. I've created an endpoint which simply returns a 201 status. I've then created a test file which checks to see that the status returned from the HTTP request is 201, but I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined` error instead. (After running npm test on the test folder) Can anyone help me find what the problem is in my files? Thank you!

**endpoints/status.js**

```js
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  res.status(201).send('You are doing a great job')
}
```

**server.js**

```js
// Import dependancies
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

// Setup express server
const app = express()

// Setup port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001))

// Parse application/json
app.use(express.json())

// Setup cors
app.use(cors())

// Import routes
const getStatus = require('./endpoints/status')
const getInfo = require('./endpoints/info')

// Setup routes
app.get('/api/status', getStatus)
app.get('/api/info', getInfo)

// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))
}

// Listen on port
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get('port')}/`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
})

// Export so we can test
module.exports = app
```

**test/server.test.js**

```js
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const server = require('../server')

chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('status', () => {
  describe('GET /status', () => {
    it('it should return the correct status', (done) => {
      chai.request(server)
        .get('/api/status')
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err !== null) {
            console.log('Status error: ', err)
          }
          res.should.have.status(201)
          done()
        })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: try chai.expect(res).to.have.status(201) ?

Comment: Can you `console.log(res)` and post the contents of the response object here?

Comment: Mocha hates the usage of arrow functions, try to avoid using them https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions